# when i click to the button the state change but the render still the same

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

i want to add new links every time i click on button
i use first useState like this :

```
 const [links, setLinks] = useState([
    {
      number: 1,
      platforms: null,
      url: null,
    },
  ]);
```

then handleClick function every time i click on button :

```
 const handleclick = () => {
    let addLinks = links;
    const newLink = {
      number: links.length + 1,
      platforms: null,
      url: null,
    };
    addLinks.push(newLink);
    return  setLinks(addLinks);
  };
```

in the runder :

```
  <h1>Customize your links</h1>
  <p>
    Add/Edit/Remove links and then share all your profiles with the world
  </p>
  
    <button
      type="button"
      class="btn btn-outline-danger "
      style={{ border: "1px solid #a009e4", color: "#a009e4" }}
      onClick={handleclick}
    >
      + Add New Link
    
  
  
    {links.map((link)=>{
       return (
            <AllLinks number={link.number} key={link.number}/>
       );
     })}
```

i try useEffect but still the same problem the value of state (links) is changed but in the browser nothing added

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you assign one variable to another (`let addLinks = links;`), you don't copy the array, just the reference to the original array. To shallow copy the array use spread: `let addLinks = [...links];`.

Since you're also creating a new state based on the previous one, you should use an updater function. Take the `prevLinks`, spread it into a new array, and add the new link:

```
const handleclick = () => {
  setLinks(prevLinks => [ // create a new array
    ...prevLinks, // add the previous links
    { // add the new link
      number: links.length + 1,
      platforms: null,
      url: null,
    }
  ])
};
```